# how can I batch copy a file into multiple sub-directories?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory called Case Files, and within it many directories labled:
Defendant 1
Defendant x
Defendant 88
Defendant !!
etc...
(btw these folders are the defendants names, they're not actually labeled 'defendant')

In each of the Defendant folders is a directory called Pleadings.  Is there a way I can copy *filexxxx.pdf* into the Pleadings folder for each defendant?  Preferably I would like to just run a simple .bat if possible.

Comment: Is filexxxx.pdf different for each defendant?

Comment: no filexxxx.pdf would be the same, however 1 condition I forgot to mention is, filexxxx.pdf may already be in Pleadings folder, in which case it can just skip or overwrite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should copy the pdf into every folder called `pleadings` under `c:\case files`

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\case files" %%a in (*)  do (
   if /i "%%~nxa"=="pleadings" copy /y "c:\folder\file.pdf" "%%a"
)
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   @echo off
   cd /d "c:\case files" 
   for /r %%d in (~)  do (
     echo %%d | find /i  "\Pleadings\~" >nul 2>&1 && copy /y "c:\filexxxx.pdf" "%%~dpd\"
    )
```

Comment: wow! thank you for such a fast response! one condition I completely forgot about, some of the defendants Pleadings folder may already contain the filexxxx.pdf, in which case it can skip or overwrite it, either way is fine.  Will this script still work in this case?

Comment: this will overwrite the file.Otherwise will propmt on each copy.Fir skipping check `xcopy` options.And check my edit.`FINDSTR` does not set proper `errorlevel` , but works fine with `FIND`

Comment: actually, the script runs the loop in the right folder (Case Files), but instead of copying filexxxx.pdf to each defendant/Pleadings folder, it is creating a file called '~' in each folder.

Comment: You can change the `"%%d"` to `"%%~dpd"` in the copy command (at the end of the line) and it should work.  If any folder in a pleadings directory has a name that starts with `~` then it will also get a copy of the PDF file.

Comment: after further inspection the '~' file _is_ the filexxxx.pdf only it has been renamed to '~' and has no extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from within the Case Files directory:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`dir /s /b Pleadings`) do copy /y filexxxx.pdf %i
```

But check my comment because I have a feeling that's not exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: With delims set to `=` it will break when a filename has an `=` in it.  delims should be set to nothing `... delims="

Comment: Ha, good point. I've been using that code for years because I just copy/paste it everytime from the documentation (``for /?``) without realizing the example was meant for environment variables. I guess I never had a file with ``=`` in the name.